# bug in next and prev buttons of carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

i create 2 carousels. Both are clone with the same .css and .js file but the problem is that the fist carousel's next and prev buttons are working properly bu the second carousel's next and prev button are not working.
Why this is happen.can you please solve it.
I also tried by renaming second carousel's classes and id's, and make another css file and js for it. but it is again not working.
please say what Can u do.
here is html file

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="carousel">
        <div id="content">
            <a href=""> <img class="item" src="images/b1.jpg" /></a>
            <a href=""> <img class="item" src="images/images (2).jpeg" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="prev">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" />
            <path d="M15.61 7.41L14.2 6l-6 6 6 6 1.41-1.41L11.03 12l4.58-4.59z" />
        </svg>
    </button>
    <button id="next">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" />
            <path d="M10.02 6L8.61 7.41 13.19 12l-4.58 4.59L10.02 18l6-6-6-6z" />
        </svg>
    </button>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="carousel">
        <div id="content">
            <a href=""> <img class="item" src="images/b1.jpg" /></a>
            <a href=""> <img class="item" src="images/images (2).jpeg" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="prev">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" />
            <path d="M15.61 7.41L14.2 6l-6 6 6 6 1.41-1.41L11.03 12l4.58-4.59z" />
        </svg>
    </button>
    <button id="next">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" />
            <path d="M10.02 6L8.61 7.41 13.19 12l-4.58 4.59L10.02 18l6-6-6-6z" />
        </svg>
    </button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 964px;
  position: relative;
}

#carousel {
  overflow: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

#carousel::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 0;
}

#prev,
#next {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  background: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
}

#prev {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  display: none;
}

#next {
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#content {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 16px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  margin: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  background: green;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
const gap = 16;
const carousel = document.getElementById("carousel"),
  content = document.getElementById("content"),
  next = document.getElementById("next"),
  prev = document.getElementById("prev");

next.addEventListener("click", e => {
  carousel.scrollBy(width + gap, 0);
  if (carousel.scrollWidth !== 0) {
    prev.style.display = "flex";
  }
  if (content.scrollWidth - width - gap <= carousel.scrollLeft + width) {
    next.style.display = "none";
  }
});
prev.addEventListener("click", e => {
  carousel.scrollBy(-(width + gap), 0);
  if (carousel.scrollLeft - width - gap <= 0) {
    prev.style.display = "none";
  }
  if (!content.scrollWidth - width - gap <= carousel.scrollLeft + width) {
    next.style.display = "flex";
  }
});

let width = carousel.offsetWidth;
window.addEventListener("resize", e => (width = carousel.offsetWidth));
```

here first carousel is perfact but seconds next and prev buttons are not working..even everything is same.

Comment: ID's are supposed to be unique on a page, next = document.getElementById("next") will only get the first button with that id on the page.

Comment: but i also tried with id="next1" and "prev1" for second carousel with another js file but the same prblm appears...please help..i am working on it from last two days...i done every possibilities..but dont know what is happening with it

Comment: **ALL** id's on a page have to be unique. So not only `next` and `prev`, but also `wrapper`,`carousel` and `content`. `content = document.getElementById("content")` will always target the first div, never the second

Comment: i also tried with "content1", "wrapper1", "carousel1" and "content1"....i want to tell you that touch and slide is working good in both carousel but onpy these buttons of second carousel are not working

Comment: You have to bind an eventlistener to **every** button. Did you also do this for next2 and prev2? I have an answer ready in a sec.

Comment: actually i gave ids for the first carousel are "next" and "prev" and for the second carousel "next1" and "prev1"...but still this is not working......i havent tried with next2 and prev2...LOTS OF THANX MANN..PLAESE HELP TO FIX THIS BUG...

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, ALL id's on a page have to be unique, otherwhise always the first one is targeted. To make it work with multiple buttons you have to set up a bit more flexible system.

Your *prev* and *next* buttons are wrapped inside a *wrapper* div that also contains *carousel* and *content*, so you don't need any id at all. You can target them using the DOM functions of javascript if you know what button is clicked. And for that there is the handy [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

Use classes to style the div's (note all id's are gone):

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="carousel">
      <div class="content">
      ....
      </div>
   </div>
   <button class="prev">...</button>
   <button class="next">...</button>
</div>
```

To bind an eventlistener to the two (or more!) **next** buttons, you then use a `queryselector` looking for all elements with a class named `next`. You can use that to bind an eventlistener to all the `next` buttons:

```
var all_next = document.querySelectorAll(".next");
all_next.forEach( function(el){
    el.addEventListener( "click", function(event){
       //get the clicked button
       var clicked_element = e.target;
       // do something here
       .... 
    }
 })
```

From the line `var clicked_element = e.target;` you now know exactly which button is clicked and work out what wrapper, carousel and container are connected with that:

```
//get the wrapper (is the parent of NEXT)
  var wrapper = clicked_element.parentNode;
//get the carousel (is first child of wrapper)
  var carousel = wrapper.children[0];
//get the content (is first child of carousel)
  var content = carousel.children[0];
```

Now you can do your magic on the required elements.

Repeat this for the `prev` buttons.

It might seem a bit more work at first, but you are know much more flexible. You can add additional wrappers without having to work out if the id isn't in use yet.

**NOTE** There might be typo's in this answer.